# When I edit a cell and press ENTER I want to update the database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, enter

let's see if anyone can help me.

I want that when I edit a cell in a DataGridView and press the ENTER key I update the database.

I have a button that does this to me, but only after editing it (without pressing ENTER), I press the button and it updates the database.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ' we will create save functions in our module
        Dim row, ID As Integer
        Dim Nombre, Apellidos, DNI, Telefono, Email As String
        ' Declare the variable to get value event click on datagridview
        row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        ID = DataGridView1(0, row).Value
        Nombre = DataGridView1(1, row).Value
        Apellidos = DataGridView1(2, row).Value
        DNI = DataGridView1(3, row).Value
        Telefono = DataGridView1(4, row).Value
        Email = DataGridView1(5, row).Value
        ' query to Update data into biodata tables
        Dim UpdateData As String = "UPDATE tbl_biodata SET Nombre='" & Nombre & "',Apellidos='" & Apellidos & "',DNI='" & DNI & "',Telefono='" & Telefono & "',Email='" & Email & "' WHERE ID=" & ID & ""
        ' call function to update data
        RunSQL(UpdateData)
        ' fill new data into datagridview1
        showData()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CellEndEdit event. Just specify your column number. Probably you have to check that all desired cell(used in query) are populated.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then 'replace 5 with your column number
        Button2.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the form designer, select the form and open properties. Set the AcceptButton property of the form to Button2. The code in the Button2 event handler will run when you press the Enter key.